# Word to encompass service, booking, order and reservation

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that can be used for services, bookings, products and reservations.

For example, at a hotel you can reserve a tennis court, book a conference room, order room service and request a wake up service.

What single word can I use that encompasses all of these?

Comment: Are you asking to describe a feature of an online service? Or is this to succinctly describe the function a person would provide at a customer service counter? Or is there some other driving need here...

Comment: I'm trying to model this domain for software development reasons.

Comment: Customer service or customer requirement. I doubt there is a single word.

Comment: Agree with @Rathony, although "Guest Services" might have a warm-fuzzier appeal to it.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I think I've got it. Not a novel word, to be honest, but it just might fit the bill.

CONCIERGE

> a usually multilingual hotel staff member who handles luggage and
>   mail, makes reservations, and arranges tours; broadly :  a person
>   employed (as by a business) to make arrangements or run errands

Unfortunately, Conde Nast Traveler has already taken the domain name, concierge.com, so if you're looking for a domain name, this doesn't help.

Comment: That is not at all what I am looking for. When I say domain, I mean it as in its definition: "a specified sphere of activity or knowledge"

Answer (score -1):

**Front-of-house** refers to all those types of services that interact with customers, doesn't it?

See [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/front-of-house):

> (often used as an adjective) the business of dealing with an audience at a theatre, for example selling tickets and programmes

Comment: C'mon -- Please add reference and link.

Comment: I've never heard of this.

Comment: @ab2 sorry. Was a bit lazy as posting off the phone. Edited.